# Differentiability of trigonometric functions with modulus

Tags: derivatives

> which of the following is not differentiable at $x=0$ ?
>
> $(A)\ \cos(|x|)+|x|\hspace{100pt}(B)\ \cos(|x|)-|x|$
>
> $(C)\ \sin(|x|)+|x|\hspace{100pt}(D)\ \sin(|x|)-|x|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D is differentiable, A, B and C aren't.
General idea is: Observe the derivative of functions separately for $x<0$ and $x>0$.

In A we have:
$$f(x)=cos(|x|)+|x|\\
1. x>0:\\
f'(x)=-sin(x)+1\\
limf'(x)=1 (x \rightarrow 0^+)\\
2. x<0:\\
f'(x)=-sin(x)-1\\
limf'(x)=-1 (x \rightarrow 0^-)\\$$
Since $limf'(x)=1 (x \rightarrow 0^+)$ and $limf'(x)=-1 (x \rightarrow 0^-)$ are different, $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.
It's similar for B and C.
In D we have:
$$f(x)=sin(|x|)-|x|\\
x>0:\ \ f'(x)=cosx-1\\
x<0:\ \ f'(x)=-cosx+1\\
limf'(x)=0 (x \rightarrow 0^+)\\
limf'(x)=0 (x \rightarrow 0^-)$$